# what are the elements of these bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex

I'm supposed to rewrite some old document into Latex and the Bibliography is as shown in the images i know most of the elements like (`\author`, `\title` ,`\pages`, `\year` ) but i don't know
 "tome 61", "2.series", `\n^o 7-13`, "t. 13" 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Series, corresponds to the biblatex `series`, tome is `volume` (and I suspect that  "t.' is the abbreviation of tome, and `n^{o}` is `number`.

Comment: The "series" bit would be the `series` field for `@article`s, "tome" looks like `volume` and "n^o" could be `number`. Note the inconsistency of "tome" vs "t." though, as well as the name formats. (The fields I mention are all available with `biblatex`, I can't be sure about BibTeX styles.) If you have to replicate the bibliography *exactly*, doing it manually via `thebibliography` might be your safest bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `.bib` entry would be:

```
@article{Serre:1955,
  title={Faisceaux alg{\'e}briques coh{\'e}rents},
  author={Serre, J.-P.},
  journaltitle={Annals of Mathematics},
  date={1955},
  series={2},
  volume={61},
  pages={197-278},
  langid={french},
}
```

The second one should be `inproceedings`, but if your style doesn't provide for it, just use `incollection` or `article` (respectively, change `eventtitle` to `booktitle` or `journaltitle`)  – whichever one gives the best result.

```
@inproceedings{Grothendieck:1960,
  title={Techniques de construction en g{\'e}om{\'e}trie analyique, I--VI},
  author={Grothendieck, Alexander},
  eventtitle={S{\'e}minaire Cartan},
  date={1960/1961},
  volume = {13},
  number={7--13},
  langid={french},
}
```

Ideally, you need `babel` and a bibliographic style that supports french references if you want the same output.

Using `babel` and the default BibLaTeX style (which is not geared for French style of citation):

[image]

Comment: Actually, everything looks great thanks but the '2.series' didn't show in the printed pdf.

Comment: Maybe your style doesn't print the `series` field? The default style does.

Answer (score 2):

In french "tome" means "volume", "number" can be abbreviated as "N^o".

So, for the first you can type:

```
@article{serre:1955,
  title={Faisceaux alg{\'e}briques coh{\'e}rents}
author={Serre, Jean-Pierre},
  journal={Annals of Mathematics},
  volume={61},
  pages={197--278},
  number={2},
  year={1955}
}
```

and the second (it's composed of 4 papers, delivered at Cartan’s seminar):

```
@article{grothendieck:1960,
  title={Techniques de construction en g{\'e}om{\'e}trie analyique, I--IV},
  author={Grothendieck, Alexander},
  journal={S{\'e}minaire Cartan},
  volume = {13},
  pages={249--276},
  number={7--13},
  year={1960-1961}
}
```

Comment: Mhhh, I don't think the "2. series" bit belongs in the `number` field. In `biblatex` at least, `@article`s can have a `series` field.

Comment: @moewe when i use 'series' field in the BibTeX it doesn't show in the printed pdf!

Comment: @mostafax80 Not all BibTeX styles support the `series` field. Since you tagged your question with `biblatex` I assumed you would be using that package, where at least all the standard styles know the `series` field and do the correct thing. (See also my comment to the question.)

Comment: Actually I was using natbib package, that is why .  Thanks